# Evince Document Viewer theme parssing error causes invisible GUI when custom GTK-3 theme is in symlink

Tags: themes, gtk3, evince

Getting following error when replacing the `.themes` folder in `$HOME` with a symbolic link pointing to content on a mounted drive:

```
(evince:28717): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:21:16.921: Theme parsing error: 
gtk.css:1:0: Failed to import: 
Error opening file $HOME/.themes/Flat-Remix-GTK-Dark-Solid/gtk-3.0/gtk.css: Permission denied


(evince:31282): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:32:54.277: 
Error loading theme icon 'dialog-password' for stock: 
Icon 'dialog-password' not present in theme Flat-Remix-Dark
```

The result is a totally invisible GUI like described [here](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues/325)

The solutions offered in the GitHub issue has been resolved with new releases, and also worth mentioning is Evince is installed through Apt, not Snap.

The GUI returns if I replace the symlink with the content in the `.themes`  folder from `$HOME`. The folder being a symlink does not seem to affect any other applications I've seen so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a wild chase I managed to find [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/409) on Evince's GitLab.
The problem is the files are in a location not approved by AppArmor and thus Evince is blocked from accessing them.

To solve the issue and continue using symlink for the `.themes` and `.icons` folders, quick answer is adding the following lines to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince`:

```
  owner {path-to-icons-folder}/.icons/** r,
  owner {path-to-themes-folder}/.themes/** r,
```

The longer answer:

first take a backup of the file `/usr/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince`

install apparmor-utils:

```
sudo apt install apparmor-utils
```

run AppArmor's scanning utility:

```
sudo aa-genprof /usr/bin/evince
```

While the utility is running, attempt to open a PDF file using Evince in another terminal window:

```
evince {name-of-your-pdf.pdf}
```

Now head back to the original terminal window and press `s` for "Scan". The utility will scan the logs for denied permission attempts for Evince by AppArmor and ask if you would like to allow Evince to access these in the future. Accept the suggestions.

Now if you try running Evince again, you'll notice a whole bunch of new permission errors. You could continue adding these until the errors stop showing, but I prefer my config files slightly less messy so I suggest editing the `/usr/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince` file. Locate the two entries added during the scan, then edit them and change the file URL to:

```
  owner {path-to-icons-folder}/.icons/** r,
  owner {path-to-themes-folder}/.themes/** r,
```

Note that this gives Evince permission to all files in the folder and sub directories, which it could potentially alter, so keep the scope small.

After saving the file, tell the AppArmor utility to scan once more. This is so AppArmor's config is updated. Now Evince should have the required permissions and show it's GUI in all it's amazing glory when you next open a PDF.

Comment: After adding those lines, I had to run `sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince` to reload the configuration. Then the error messages went away and the GUI showed up. The OP writes: "The folder being a symlink does not seem to affect any other applications I've seen so far." Looking at `/etc/apparmor.d/`, there are only a few programs that are controlled by apparmor.